# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: MessageDrivenBean: Timer Service methods not allowed from state = CREATING

Tags: sharepoint, websphere, ibm-mq

[image]

Can someone please advise how I can resolve this issue. I am seeing this error on my WAS application SystemOut.logs.

Comment: First, don't post screen-shots, copy & paste the logfile. Second, the error message is pretty clear: you cannot use a Timer in an OnMessage method.

Answer (score 1):

Section 5.5.1 of the EJB 3.2 Specification indicates that Timer service and Timer methods are not accessible from the constructor, during injection, or post construct.
`ejbCreate` would be the post construct method for the bean, so calling TimerService.getTimers() is not permitted.

Basically, you'll need to move that call to a message listener method. That doesn't work so well if you really need to do that as part of application start.

Would it work to use a non-persistent automatic timer, such that it would be created automatically for you whenever the application starts?  (i.e `@Schedule`)